# Hello everyone , selection of image using image picker controller

Tags: ios, image, uitableview

> When attempting to present a modal view controller on a navigation controller the navigation controller is popping all of my view controllers underneath when the modal is dismissed.

So after pushing a few view controllers and presenting a modal on the topViewController, I end up back at the rootViewController when the modal is dismissed.

Anyone had this happen to them lately, I can't seem to find the reasoning for why this is happening?

```
func selectImageClicked(_ sender:UIButton)
{
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

    let alert=UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Select", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let camera=UIAlertAction(  title: "Camera", style: .default) { (action) in
         imagePicker.sourceType = .camera

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    let gallery=UIAlertAction(  title: "Gallery", style: .default) { (action) in
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    let cancel=UIAlertAction(  title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
    }

    alert.addAction(camera)
    alert.addAction(gallery)
    alert.addAction(cancel)

    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    if (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage) != nil
    {

        objectAuctionItemDetail.itemImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.tblTableView.reloadData()
     }
}
```